# How to I load a map of Madeira into Drive+

Tags: maps

We are heading on Madeira on holiday, and as I love the how my Windows Phone has of-line maps, I wish to get the map loaded before we arrive.  But when I to so “setting” and look at the list of maps I can download Madeira is not included.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that Madeira is a Portuguese province, it should be included in the map of Portugal.

I just tested it on my Lumia 950 - downloaded the offline map for Portugal, enabled flight mode and verified that the Maps app shows full detail for Madeira. I see you mentioned Drive+, which means you're using WP 8.1, but the underlying maps should still be the same.

Comment: Thanks that works, I just did not consider it being on a Portuguese map in the same way as I would not look for the Folklands on a UK map.